# Try changing the name to follow the snake_case style

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuWl1.jpg)

I try to changed the name but it not works. Please help me to finish my home work, i ever try like debug, runn, and ask some people but they arenn't know abaout this. Help me please!!

Comment: "I try to changed the name but it not works". What did you exactly try? Because it really is just about changing the file names to snake_case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot there is a uppercase at the beggining of the file name. It might cause the error. I also know that when you're renamming a file with just case modifications sometimes the linter doesn't see it

Comment: How to flutter machine know, that i have changed

Comment: change a letter like add "z" at the end and then change back to the previous name

Answer (score 0):

File name must use only lower_case, use underscore "_" for spacing. You are welcome.